# Task in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, task

The error is below,

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure
> to publish values from the main thread (via operators like
> receive(on:)) on model updates.

How can I add this function to the task and return the task.?

```
func fetchAdPosts() async {

    Task {
        do{
            let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Ads")
            
            let ads = try await db.getDocuments()

            //error in the below code lines
            self.ads = ads.documents.compactMap({ ad in
                return try? ad.data(as: AdPost.self)
            })
            
        }
        catch{
            
            self.alertMessage = error.localizedDescription
            showAlert.toggle()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Assuming `self` here is a ObservableObject you have to mark it as a `MainActor`, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69557131/12299030.

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if the function is already `async`, you don't really need to wrap the entire body in a `Task` as well.
You don't need to introduce a new `async` context when you are already in one.

To resolve the error, ensure that the function is in an `ObservableObject` `class` marked `@MainActor`.

```swift
@MainActor class MyController: ObservableObject {
    // properties...
    
    func fetchAdPosts() async {
        do {
            let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Ads")
            
            let ads = try await db.getDocuments()
            
            self.ads = ads.documents.compactMap({ ad in
                return try? ad.data(as: AdPost.self)
            })
        } catch {
            self.alertMessage = error.localizedDescription
            showAlert.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the assignment to `self.ads` takes place on the main actor, which is required for `ObservableObject` instances.
The main actor context will be inherited for all properties and methods on a class marked `@MainActor`.